# What would happen if I filter on timestamp using date in snowflake sql?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake. What will happen if I use 'timestamp between start_date and end_date' in the where clause?

I made a few tries in my snowflake db, its result looks weird to me.
For example, i use "between '2023-04-01' and '2023-04-10' " and I saw only one record from '2023-04-10' which was around 3am and it was the earlest one for the day. However, there are supposed to be 14 more records in '4-10'. Then i tried "between '2023-04-01' and '2023-04-11' " then all records on Apr 10th shown up but I got 0 records for Apr 11st. There are supposed to be some records on Apr 11st as well.

I know the solution would be changing it into something like '2023-04-10 23:59:59' but I am just curious about what's going on. Why did I get only 1 record when i put '2023-04-10' as the end date

Comment: It may be a timestamp problem. Pl note snowflake by default works in PST timezone and if you are checking from EST, 3AM EST is still <12AM PST - which make sense.

Comment: For Snowflake there is system level timezone setting, it is PST by default or it could have been updated to something else after the Snowflake account is setup. Then there is session level timezone by default the session level timezone matches with the system level timezone. Play with changing them and see how the output is changing.